# Solving a system of equations over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, systems-of-equations

I was given the following problem:

> Solve over $\mathbb{Q}$ the system $S=\begin{cases}
>         x + y  - 6z = 21 \\ 5x - 2y +2z = 2 \\ 3x +7y +z = 10
>     \end{cases}$

See that
$$\begin{align}
   B&:= \begin{bmatrix}        
        5 & -2& 2 &    \rightarrow 2 \\
        1 & 1 & -6&    \rightarrow 21 \\
        3 & 7 & 1 & \rightarrow 10
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

is the matrix associated to $S$. I will skip the process of transforming $\mathbf{B}$ into an upper diagonal matrix. Suffices to say through that method we arrive to the unique solution $$\mathbb{S}=\begin{cases} x=1 \\ y = 2 \\ z = -3 \end{cases}$$

There is a theorem that states that if the associated matrix $\mathbf{B}^{n\times m}$ of a system $S$ has dimensions $n = m$ ($n$ number of variables, $m$ number of equations), there will be a *unique* solution if and only if $\textbf{B}$ is diagonizable with $B_{ij}\neq 0$ whenever $i = j$. This is the case for $\mathbf{B}$. What's important to my question is the word *unique*.

If $\mathbb{S}$ is the *only* solution to $S$, then what does it mean to solve $S$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? It is a trivial observation to say the values of the solution belong to $\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  Generally speaking "solve [X] over [Y]" means "find all of the elements of [Y] which satisfy [X]".  If your system has a unique solution, and that solution is an element of $\mathbb{Q}$, solving that system of $\mathbb{Q}$ means finding that unique solution.  Can you explain your confusion?

Comment: In truth, what confused me was that all the excercises of this form I was given have a unique solution, all of which belong to $\mathbb{Q}$. So the condition of solving over $\mathbb{Q}$ felt kind of trivial, unless I was missinterpreting it (which is what I assumed).

Comment: If this is just coincidental then I should delete the question.

Comment: I mean, it *isn't* coincidental, in the sense that if a system of linear equations with rational coefficients has a unique solution, that solution must be rational (this is a consequence of the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, and $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: That's actually illuminating and makes me feel a little bit dumb for having asked this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Formally speaking, a system of equations has to be solved over _something_. That is, what would it mean to solve this system if it wasn't given which set you would solve it over? Nothing. You could have, then, solved it over any field, say $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and proclaimed that as your solution. You seem to be assuming, though, that a system is generally solved over $\mathbb{R}$ unless otherwise specified, which is fine, but strictly formally incorrect. That's why your textbook is specifying what to solve over – not to confuse you or make you discard solutions, but to be completely unambiguous.

Comment: @zaq That does make sense. Thank  you for the extra clarification.

Comment: Take the three left columns of your $B,$   call that square matrix $C$  for coefficients. Make column vector of the constants of the right column,  call it $  V =(2,21,10)^T.$   Finally  make the variables  $X = (x,y,z)^T.$    The system is then $CX = V$  It turns out that $C$  is invertible, which is all we need to know to force $ X = C^{-1} V$  as the unique solution. Because $C^{-1}CX = C^{-1}V........$